# The right way to use tikz in a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making a table where I want simple tikz line drawings in the cells. This is my first attempt to use tikz so I am likely to have made all sorts of mistakes. This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
        Apple & Apple & Apple\\
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=] (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=] (B) at (1,1);
        \draw (A) -- (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}&    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=] (A) at (1,0);
        \coordinate node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=] (B) at (0,1);
        \draw (A) -- (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}   &   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=] (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=] (B) at (1,1);
        \coordinate node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=] (C) at (2,1);
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
        \end{tikzpicture}  
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It does in fact works however:

- It gives me an error message "Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text". How should I fix that?
- It seems very wordy for such a simple task. Do I really need a separate tikzpicture environment for each cell for example?

Comment: Yes, because of `\coordinate node....`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use nodes, you need to give them some content, even a `{}` is allowed. But you do not really need to use nodes to fill some circles. And yes, you need to start a `tikzpicture` whenever you want to have one, or you could use the shorthand `\tikz{...}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
        Apple & Apple & Apple\\
        \hline
        \tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) circle[radius=1pt] -- (1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
        \path (0,1.2);}
        &    
        \tikz{\draw[fill] (1,0) circle[radius=1pt] -- (0,1) circle[radius=1pt];
        \path (0,1.2);}
        &   
        \tikz{\draw[fill] (0,0) circle[radius=1pt] -- (1,1) circle[radius=1pt]
        -- (2,1) circle[radius=1pt];\path (0,1.2);}
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However the vertical spacing between the top of the lines and the long horizontal line has disappeared. How can that be put back?

Comment: @Anush I am not sure there was a padding but it easy to add one. (There are zillions of possibilities.)

Comment: Have you just created an invisible point at coordinate (0,1.2) using \path?

Comment: @Anush Yes. That is one possible way.

Comment: Thank you. I am completely new to this so even one way is great to learn :)